# How to calculate a price of a product with custom size?

Tags: price

I’m new to Magento and trying to develop an extension that will do the following.

I have a product with standard dimensions (like 600 x 2000 mm, 700 x 2000 mm) but the product can be also made in any custom size (like 654 x 2102 mm etc).

There must be an option to switch from drop-down window with a list of standard sizes to a text field, so a client can insert its desired dimensions.

And the most complicated part is calculating the price. The price is calculated according to the following logic: find nearest bigger standard size (by area) and add 10%.

What would be the best approach to doing this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using price modifier is likely the simplest way without changing your whole catalog:

In a custom module, you need in the etc folder a `di.xml` with the content below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom-pricing" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Mbs\PriceWidget\Model\PriceModifier</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">90</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

then the class will be called for all your products (so be careful your calculations do not create overhead), but then if you only apply your customisation when standard dimensions has a value, you may have something working quickly.

```
<?php

namespace Mbs\PriceWidget\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\PriceModifierInterface;

class PriceModifier implements PriceModifierInterface
{
    private static $chargeForRange600_2000 = 23;

    public function modifyPrice($price, Product $product)
    {
        if ($product->getStandardDimensions() === '600 x 2000') {
            return $price + self::$chargeForRange600_2000;
        }

        return $product->getPrice();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks again! will try this